# Swift & PromiseKit: Resolving ALL promises from a loop

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, promise, promisekit

I'm looking for a solution in Swift3 to resolve a dynamic number of promises all at once, e.g. like this sample in JavaScript:

```
var promises = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var promise = $http.get('/data' + i);
    promises.push(promise);
}
$q.all(promises).then(doSomethingAfterAllRequests);
```

https://daveceddia.com/waiting-for-promises-in-a-loop/

There was a library call 'Craft' for Swift2 that could do that (https://github.com/supertommy/craft), but it's no longer maintained.

Does anyone know if or how I could do that with PromiseKit or another library?

Thx a bunch!

Answer (score 11):

You can look into `when` which may provide what you need and is covered [here](http://promisekit.org/docs/handbook/Functions.html#/s:F10PromiseKit4whenurFT9fulfilledGSaGCS_7Promisex___GS0_GSax__).

Use the loop to put your promises into an array and then do something like this:

```
when(fulfilled: promiseArray).then { results in
    // Do something
}.catch { error in
    // Handle error
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much, perfect answer!
I was so fixated on the .all that I didn't realize the array in the when().
I also found this one on the way, quite useful, but objective-c: 
http://philmitchell.github.io/PromiseKit/

Comment: I have independent requests, which are not dependent on each other. The issue with fulfilled is if first has an error it will not go ahead for 2nd request and I will not get a response in done. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: @HardikDG You can use the `when(resolved: )` variant. This will wait on all of the provided promises, and then give you an array of all of their results.